# Error when disposing of OrthagonalTiledMapRenderer

Tags: java, libgdx

Im running into a problem while disposing of a screen. I am getting this error message when I try to dispose of my OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer. I looked around online and didnt find see any other examples of this or situations where this happened.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer not allocated with newUnsafeByteBuffer or already disposed
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.disposeUnsafeByteBuffer(BufferUtils.java:507)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexArray.dispose(VertexArray.java:67)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.dispose(Mesh.java:551)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.dispose(SpriteBatch.java:944)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.BatchTiledMapRenderer.dispose(BatchTiledMapRenderer.java:152)
at org.shawnhenry.rollypauly.screens.GameScreen.dispose(GameScreen.java:264)
at org.shawnhenry.rollypauly.screens.GameScreen.hide(GameScreen.java:238)
at org.shawnhenry.rollypauly.InputHandler.doTap(InputHandler.java:147)
at org.shawnhenry.rollypauly.InputHandler.touchUp(InputHandler.java:117)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:305)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:199)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

My implementation is quite simple.

In my main method I initilize the renderer:

```
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(world.getTiledMap());
```

The render method called the renderer to draw objects like:

```
renderer.render(backgroundLayers);
```

and

```
renderer.getSpriteBatch().draw(resume, world.getResumeButton().x, world.getResumeButton().y, world.getResumeButton().width, world.getResumeButton().height);
```

Here is the trace through my various classes/functions mentioned in the error message:

FROM "InputHandler"

```
if(mainMenu.contains(x, y)){//Tapped the mainMenu button.
    //Gdx.app.log("InputHandler", "Hit menu button!");
    gameScreen.getGame().setScreen(new LevelSelectScreen(gameScreen.getGame()));
    gameScreen.hide();
}
```

FROM "GameScreen"

```
@Override
public void hide() {
     dispose();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    renderer.dispose();
    //world.dispose();
}
```

Any help you can give me would be great.  If I dispose of my world class, and not renderer I dont get an error.  My concern is that I believe the renderer is a resource heavy object so when leaving the screen it needs to be disposed of.

Comment: You can't dispose something twice, so you are getting the error. Try to find where else you might have disposed of your renderer besides in the GameScreen, or whether you are calling `dispose` (or `hide`, since you have it indirectly calling dispose) twice on your GameScreen..

Answer (score 1):

I believe solved my problem.  I figured I was calling dispose twice, but I looked through my entire code and the only place I called `dispose()` was the one time during the `hide()` and the `hide()` was only being called once during this:

```
if(mainMenu.contains(x, y)){//Tapped the mainMenu button.
   //Gdx.app.log("InputHandler", "Hit menu button!");
   gameScreen.getGame().setScreen(new LevelSelectScreen(gameScreen.getGame()));
   gameScreen.hide();
}
```

My problem I believe is that when I set the new screen to the `LevelSelectScreen()` the `hide()` function is automatically called as the the `LevelSelectScreen()` gains focus...`dispose()` is called for the first time.  Then it is called again in the very next line when I explicitly call it `gameScreen.hide()'`.